# Jagged Edge Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to store some data in (I guess a semi-2, semi-3d array) in PHP (5.3)
What I need to do is store data about each floor like this:

```
Floor    Num of Spots    Handicap          Motorcyle        Other
1         100            array(15,16,17)    array (47,62)   array (99,100)
2         100            array(15,16,17)    array (47,62)   array (99,100)
and on
```

The problem is, is if the Handicap+Motorcyle+Other were ints, I could just store the data in a 2d array. However, they aren't. So I was thinking I could make something almost like a 3D array, with the first two columns only being in 2D.

The other thought I had was making a 2D array and for columns 3,4, and 5 instead of saving as

```
array(15,16)
//save like
1516
```

And then split at two digits (1 digit array numbers would be prefaced with a 0). However, I am wondering about the limit of the length of a string, because if I decide to move to a 3 digit length number in the array, like array(100, 104), and I need to store alot of numbers, I am thinking I am going to quickly exceed the max.

**Edit 1**
I like Omar's answer alot, but I'm not sure as to how to pull the data out.

Comment: Should mention, the reason for the title, is because I was taught that uneven column length 2D arrays were called "jagged" edge.

Comment: You could store an array in an array - where's the problem?

Comment: How would I store that array and then reference it later then... , like [0][0][0]? Never have attempted to store an array in an array, and have never done an array thats not 1 or 2d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you could store them as `?D` array, there is another approach you might want to consider :

```
$stuff = array (
  'floor1' => 
  array (
    'NumSpots' => 100,
    'handicap' => array (15,16,17),    
    'motorcycle' => array (47, 62),
    'other' =>  array (99, 100),
    ),
  ),
  'floor2' => 
    'NumSpots' => 100,
    'handicap' => array (15,16,17),    
    'motorcycle' => array (47, 62),
    'other' => array (99, 100),
    ),
  )
)
```

That way, you can access things through mroe meaningful names like

```
$stuff['floor1']['motorcycle'][2]
```

Comment: Ok so this answers my question with Omar's answer. Not sure who I should award the points to. I  wish I could give you both the check :(

Comment: I think since you explained how to get the data out, I awarded you the answer and him an upvote.

Comment: I try to implemement this, if instead of using 'floor2' (string) I use an int like Omar's solution does, how do I get the number of floors.

Comment: @chriscct7 -- To get the size of the array in Omar's example use:  `count($floors);`

Answer (score 2):

In php you can have named keys for your arrays. Each element in your array can have different types so you could have

```
$floors = array(
    1 => array(
            'num_spots' => 100,
            'handicap' => array(15,16,17)
        ),   

    2 => array(
            'num_spots' => 100,
            'handicap' => array(15,16,17),
            'motorcycle' => array (47,62)
        )
);
```

etc...

Comment: Oh, thats cool. But how do I pull the data out then? 
If I want to pull out numspots for floor 1, do I go $floors[1][num_spots] or $floors[0][0]? And how do I pull the array out?

Comment: $floors[1]['num_spots'] and $floors[1]['handicap'][0], $floors[1]['handicap'][1] ... $floors[1]['handicap'][n]

Comment: Typo above, meant to say Jeremy answered it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly that. Example:

```
$a = array();
$a[1] = array(
    'spots' => 100,
    'handicap' => array(5,3,5)
);
$a[2] = array(
    'spots' => 50,
    'handicap' => array(1,3,20)
);
var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array
  1 => 
    array
      'spots' => int 100
      'handicap' => 
        array
          0 => int 5
          1 => int 3
          2 => int 5
  2 => 
    array
      'spots' => int 50
      'handicap' => 
        array
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 3
          2 => int 20
```

You can use the array indices for the floor number or have a separate key/value for that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
$floors = array();
$floors[1] => array(
    Spaces => 100,
    Handicapped => array(15, 16, 17),
    Motorcycle => array(47, 62),
    Other => array (1, 2, 3, ..., n)
)
```

You can then retrieve the values as ...

```
$Floor1Spaces = $floors[1]['Spaces']; //An integer
$Floor1HAndicapped = $floors[1]['Handicapped']; //A 1-dimensional array of integer
```

Comment: Other is actually special-cases that aren't motorcyle or handicap.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point, so next time I'll make sure to explain everything a bit more.